# Django setup application on openshift which also run on local machine

Tags: python, django

How to create and setup Python Django application for OpenShift, which should also run on local machine.

Here I'm very confused after seeing directory structure of `rhc` created project and `django-admin.py` created project. Both creates different directory structure and files.

**RHC Creates:**

```
dj17test/
├── app.py.disabled
├── data
├── libs
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── wsgi
    ├── application
    └── static
        └── README
```

**django-admin.py Creates:**

```
dj17_created_by_dj_admin/
├── dj17_created_by_dj_admin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

How will I merge both to run on OpenShift(`rhc`) cloud and as well as on local machine using `python manage.py runserver`?

Answer (score 1):

This fork of the OpenShift Django starter project walks you through it.

https://github.com/rancavil/django-openshift-quickstart/wiki/Tutorial-How-create-an-application-with-Django-1.6-on-Openshift

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as is created. You can also add a remote for the openshift-django [example](https://github.com/openshift/django-example) or just check the repo for better understanding.

Another option is using a DIY app (without specifing django) and then you can control everything, including folder structure etc.  Another example you can use as a seed for this approach with openshift and django is [here](https://github.com/seedofjoy/openshift-diy-nginx-uwsgi-django)

Comment: The rhc created app doesn't run locally (manage.py runserver fails not finding the application)